# php process run in background and output redirect to mail

Tags: php, email, background, output

How to run php process(script) in background and script output mail.

Ex.:

1. One request call to file abc.php
2. abc.php call one script that run in background backgroundScript.php script `exec('php backgroundScript.php 2>&1 &')` That run in background but need to get output in mail not file.
3. backgroundScript.php run in background abc.php execution finished.

Now how can i got backgroundScript.php script output in mail with exec or any other command?

---

Nothing wrong with exec, But I need to mail output of backgroundscript process, and main script next command execution flow continue... no wait for backgroudscript process.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What's wrong with `exec`? Is the problem just that you can't send an email from a php script?

Answer (score 0):

Try piping your output in your exec line to mailx command

```
 | mailx -s 'Hi' 'xyz@abc.com'
```

Or most likely you are using sendmail

```
 | sendmail -s "My Test Email Subject" test@email.com
```

So try the following:

```
exec('php backgroundScript.php | sendmail -s "My Test Email Subject" test@email.com 2>&1 &')
```

Answer (score 0):

To send an email from a php script use the `mail` function:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php